# A word problem related to division/remainders

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> A gang of 17 bandits stole a chest of gold coins.
>   When they tried to divide the coins equally among themselves, there were
>   three left over. This caused a fight in which one bandit was killed. When the
>   remaining bandits tried to divide the coins again, there were ten left over.
>   Another fight started, and five of the bandits were killed. When the survivors
>   divided the coins, there were four left over. Another fight ensued in which
>   four bandits were killed. The survivors then divided the coins equally among
>   themselves, with none left over. What is the smallest possible number of coins
>   in the chest?

This looks like a job for Division Algorithm and by extension Chinese Remainder Theorem. Let $x$ be the number of coins. Then by Division Algorithm,

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x =  17q + 3 \\ 
x = 16q + 10 \\ 
x = 11q + 4 \\
x = 7q + 0
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

Is it a false start?

Comment: This looks correct so far.

Comment: All the $q$'s are different. You should denote them differently. E.g., $q_1,q_2,q_3,q_4$.

Comment: Now simply apply Chinese Remainder Theorem and you're done.

Comment: Thank you, guys. Does $x = 17q + 3 \to x \equiv 3 \pmod {17}$?

Comment: By definition: $x\equiv 3\pmod{17}\iff x=17q_1+3$ for some integer $q_1$. Your problem is equivalent to the system $x\equiv 3\pmod {17}, x\equiv 10\pmod{16}, x\equiv 4\pmod{11}, x\equiv 0\pmod 7$.

Comment: @ user236182, thank you. The problem resolved :)